# How to install Epson Stylus SX435W printer on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing

Just escaped from Windows XP and finding my way in Ubuntu 14.04 32bit. Please help me find and install drivers for Epson Stylus SX435 printer and get it working. In system settings printer shows as SX445 and despite changes always defaults to this. Have searched the net and found conflicting advice. IE use SX400 series driver and it will work perfectly or printer will only work in wireless mode. Some forum posts claim it will not work at all.
The dialogue screen on the printer just shows "unavailable" or "communication error".
I need some idiot proof advice please.

Answer (score 1):

Install common printer drivers in Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debconf ghostscript libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libc-bin libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libusb-1.0-0 lsb-base poppler-utils procps
```

Then use the printer with the application `system-config-printer-gnome`