# How to install printer on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: printing, epson

I have Epson SX435W printer, when I go to Printers->Add there are no printers.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8gNrxwF.png]

When I click on Find then I have this dialog:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7IAJ.png]

The root password is wrong but I dont have other password

Printer is turned on and connected to my laptop, drivers, lsb are installed. Scanner is woring properly.

[How to install Epson Stylus SX435W printer on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496922/how-to-install-epson-stylus-sx435w-printer-on-ubuntu-14-04-32bit) this solution didnt worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Epson Stylus SX435W printer on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496922/how-to-install-epson-stylus-sx435w-printer-on-ubuntu-14-04-32bit)

Comment: did above driver install work ?   issue this to see what drivers you have installed ... dpkg -l|grep cups

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FSSCwBag.png solution above did not worked

Comment: What does that picture show / tell us ?

Comment: I cant see the driver but it is installed

Answer (score 2):

I am going to recommend you download a printer driver from Epson; and if you do that, I would recommend you open your PRINTERS folder before that, and delete any existing `SX435` icons there; as you say they do not work.

So if you go ahead, this link [Drivers & Downloads | Epson](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16876&DSCCHK=b32e8a0bd44cc61369c3fa75fbab6b877ce71d25) is through the Epson website [Download Center | EPSON](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) when I search on `SX430` and `SX435`: Epson only list a driver for the 430 and they call it Full Feature; for a 64bit system, one downloads the `epson-inkjet-printer-201105w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` and for 32bit (ubuntu), the `epson-inkjet-printer-201105w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb`

If you click to download, and select the OPEN option from the dialogue, gdebi installer or the software centre will then INSTALL the file; and hopefully run a setup in the background so a configured printer option should be ready and waiting

EDIT: since I answered above, you have edited your first post; please tell us "Printer is turned on and connected to my laptop" how it is connected